# py2app importing numpy on a clean MAC sonoma

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I have a python project that was pack with py2app on MAC Sonoma, it runs on the computer.

when I send my app to a computer (another MAC Sonoma) that has no python/numpy/pip ect. installed,
I get this error

```
import numpy as np
```

File "/Applications/MYapp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.12/numpy/**init**.py", line 135, in 
raise ImportError(msg) from e
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
your python interpreter from there.

I work with
python 3.12
numpy 1.26.4

I expect my app to run on any mac Sonoma computer without the user need to install more stuff.